# Error Magento 2.4 <required> Zend\Serializer\Adapter\Json $jsonSerializer

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4, magento2.4.2, magento2.4.5

Error Magento 2.4

Error loading Wordpress Posts => Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter #4 [  Zend\Serializer\Adapter\Json $jsonSerializer

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing:

```
<?php
    
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;
    
use Zend\Serializer\Adapter\Json;
...
```

To:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;
...
```